# Javascript prompt to display on PHP echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I asked this question before, and I'm trying to run it but I'm having a problem displaying the input from javascript prompt to php, I'm getting "UNDEFINED INDEX" on the PHP part. I think I've almost done everything that I saw on the internet, but still no luck. Here's my javascript and ajax (script src="jquery.js" is included):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var name = prompt('Please enter your name');
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: name,
    success: function(data){ 
      console.log(data);
    }       
}); 
</script>
```

Everytime I try to alert "data", it just displays a bunch of HTML codes I have for this file. Here's my php file..

```
<?php
$response = $_POST['data'];
echo "Hello ".$response;
?>
```

I've tried enclosing my php file inside a form with a post action, but still the same error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of `data: name`, I think you want `data: {name: name}`

Comment: I'm still getting undefined index.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var name = prompt('Please enter your name');

$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {name : name},
    success: function(data){ 
      console.log(data);
    }       
}); 

<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    // get post data name from ajax

    $response = $_POST['name'];

    echo "Hello ".$response;


    // stop executing other codes to test it
    die();
}


?>
```

Comment: it doesn't display anything

Answer (score 0):

change your data option data: name, to  data: { "data":name},

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = prompt('Please enter your name');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test5.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: { "data":name},
        success: function(data){ 
          console.log(data);
        }       
    }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: still getting undefined index on $_POST['data']

Answer (score -1):

Try this will work for you,

You have to use name value pairs to pass data

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var name = prompt('Please enter your name');
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: 'name='+name,
    success: function(data){ 
      console.log(data);
    }       
}); 
</script>
```

test.php

```
<?php

echo $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: still getting undefined index.

Comment: why down vote. This will work exactly. Data will pass through `Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` this header.

Comment: use my files. This won't through error. It's working here well tested.

Comment: AJAX data attribute can accept name=value&name1=value&..., like this format too. jQuery `serialize` api will return the same format.

Comment: it's not me. I can't down vote yet. I think you need 125 reputation to down vote.

Comment: Okay. May be some genius did. He may have reason but he can explain to us why he pressed the down vote.

Comment: I tried changing the content type, still the same. I'm using localhost, btw. I'm not sure if that detail is going to be helpful or not...

Answer (score -1):

replace `data: name` with `data: JSON.stringify({"name": name})` and use `contentType: "application/json"` instead of `dataType:'text'`

```
var name = prompt('Please enter your name');
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({"name": name}),
    success: function(data){ 
      console.log(data);
    }       
}); 
</script>
```

and in your php script query for 'name', not data

```
<?php
$response = $_POST["name"];
echo "Hello ".$response;
?>
```

**Edit:** to solve the empty array problem

```
 <?php
    $temp = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $_POST = json_decode($temp, true);
    $response = $_POST["name"];
    echo "Hello ".$response;
    ?>
```

**Another Edit:** changing the contentType to not include json

The script:

```
var name = prompt('Please enter your name');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        data: $.param({"name": name}),
        success: function(data){ 
          console.log(data);
        }       
    }); 

    </script>
```

In the server:

```
<?php
    $response = $_POST["name"];
    echo "Hello ".$response;
    ?>
```

Comment: still getting undefined index

Comment: please see the edit. use contentType: "application/json" instead of dataType:'text'

Comment: I'm using localhost, btw. I'm not sure if that detail is going to be helpful or not...

Comment: please do a var_dump($_POST); to see what it contains.

Comment: this is the issue. Are you doing any redirection ?

Comment: not that i know of.. it's just one page. I created it using Dreamweaver, does it make any difference?

Comment: lets give it another shot. See the Another edit portion. Now we are not using json contentType

Comment: still undefined. here's my file structure html, head, script(jquery)/close, head, body, script(ajax)/close, php/close, body. Is it correct?